# different way to upload file

Tags: file, file-upload

Is there a way to upload a file by copying a file from the desktop and pasting it into a text input which will obviously just display the filename, rather than going through the file window and selecting the file?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify OS, software, context, or something that makes the question a bit more clear?

Comment: can you upload a file from your computer to a directory on a server just by the filename from your computer in a text input in a form?

Comment: Windows, *nix, Mac OS? FTP, http?

Comment: basically i want to copy a file from any operating system and paste it to an input then on the paste it automatically uploads it to the ftp directory with some php and javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about web applications, that could be possible if you install a custom ActiveX object or even a Java applet, or maybe trying to exploit a browser vulnerability. But, most straight way to do that will be using a `<input type='file'>`

For client applications, you can do that, if your current user have appropriate permissions, like accessing your file system and accessing your web server through HTTP.

Anyways, you must provide more details to get more concrete answers.

Comment: can you change the <input type='file'> to accept the file name rather than having a button to display the upload window?

Comment: not through programming, as that could be a security problem: imagine if I could force you to upload any document without your acknowledge...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible and should not be possible as this is a security issue. Consider the following scenario:

A malicious site example.com shows you a harmless looking form where they have hidden such a file upload textfield with the already inserted value '/etc/passwd'. They have used either a hidden_field or just display:none with CSS.

You fill in the form and submit without knowing you have also sent a file.